# SSD with Linux installation shows in windows

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, partitioning, kubuntu

Due to the convenience of only needing one PC, I have two OSs in my System. On one SSD I am running Windows and on another, I run Kubuntu Linux.

**Problem:** A 512MB Fat32 partition on the Linux SSD is showing in the windows file explorer. I tried hiding it but for some reason, it can't be hidden.

**Question:** Can I just format/delete this partition? Is it a kind of backup/recovery partition?

I couldn't find someone with this problem. So I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?  [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mess with this partition, most likely it is the EFI boot partition for Kubuntu.
The easiest way to make it invisible from Windows is to just deallocate the drive letter.